# application.css not including other style definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1

Here is my understanding as to how layouts should be applied:

a. application. html.erb has the following helper method -

```
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %> `
```

and it basically says: "use application.css file and do whatever is mentioned there.

b. Application.css files has a directive to include all stylesheet files in the directory where it resides.

```
= `require_tree` .
```

(I have added the line above to the bottom of the application.css)

---

The problem is that the file products.css.scss is never applied to the page. When I go the the Developer Tools in chrome it shows that scaffolds.css is applied to the page. *(Wanted to attach the pic but I can't as it is limited to new users)*

I've been fighting with this thing for a while and can't figure it out. 
I need to find a way for application.css to do what it was supposed to do, to use the style definitions from the same directory and it is not happening.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the solution.
in the index.htm.erb there was a block

```
<table class>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
```

I changed it to (see the first line)

```
<table class = "products">
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
```

But the ting is - I have no idea why it started working, I have found this solution on the errata web page for the book that I'm reading, somebody just offered this as a solution.
I'd appreciate if somebody can shed some light as to why this line helped.

Comment: It's actually Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 :) It'll also help to include a tag like [tag:ruby-on-rails-3] and/or [tag:ruby-on-rails-3.1]

Comment: can you please post the code from application.css and can you confirm that products.css.scss has content?

Comment: @ stephenmurdoch  
application.css looks like this now (I removed the require_tree . from the bottom)  

/*  
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory  
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide   styles to this file and they'll appear at  
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create   a new file per style scope.  
* = require_self
*= require_tree . 
*/

Comment: @ stephenmurdoch  ---- I've provided a solution (See the update section on the original post). but I'd appreciate if you can shed some light as to why this helped. ("products" corresponds to the table in my database and to the controller name)

Answer (score 2):

The directives to include are stylesheets are supposed to be in the comments only.

Drop the `=require_tree.` that is not in the comments and make sure that the comment directives are formatted with the same spacing.

You don't have to change it from the defaults.

Comment: OK, I removed the line and my application.css is back to it's default state. It didn't help unfortunately, still devtools show that scaffolds.css is applied.

Comment: is there a scaffolds.css in one of the asset directories?

Comment: @ natedavisolds |||
Yes, it is in the same directory as application.css. I've tried deleting it, but it doesn't help. Spooky...
Correction: it does change something in a way that devtools show on the page 'user agent stylesheet' instead of scaffolds.css - but ot doesn't apply products.css.scss located in the same directory (the one I need to apply)

Comment: `=require_tree .` loads all the styles. If you don't want it, you should delete it.  Also, restart the server.

Comment: 1. Line has been removed as per comments above. Didn't help though.  2. Server has been restarted but it didn't help either. (In fact it shouldn't be restarted if I use default configuration created by the scafflding>)

Comment: ===== I've provided a solution (See the update section on the original post). but I'd appreciate if you can shed some light as to why this helped. ("products" corresponds to the table in my database and to the controller name)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that if you look at the product.css.scss is has to have a table with a class as "products".

All the css directives are nested under the .products {}.

So if you do not have a table with a class set to "products", there then there is no css to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as farout supplied (and easier than you should believe):

The scaffolding doesn´t tag your table-tag with the correct class, and you have to edit the code manually to insert the "products"-class for it:

```
<table class="products">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*= require_tree .
```

should include all your stylesheets in the current directory. but why do you have it at two places. try removing the require tree from the final line.

Answer (score 0):

First, the line `<table class=>` in the code example is incomplete, has to be `<table class="products">`.
Second, the line `= require_tree` at the file `application.css`, was not necessary for me, so comment it.
Third, reload your `localhost:3000/products` or whatever is your page direction and if it doesn't work reload the server.

All that recomendations did work at least for me, try it!