# rails 3.2.1 stylesheet not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading the "agile web development with rails" book and ran into a problem at the end of chapter 6. Basically, what I have done so far is defined a sass stylesheet (products.css.scss) and linked it to my application in layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't load when i run the server and visit the page!

any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. What makes this solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

i just spent an hour figuring out the answer, since been having the exact same issue myself. go to your application.css.sass and make sure it has

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

in it. this auto loads all the other .css.sass in apps/assets/stylesheets, then precompiles them into public/assets/stylesheets to be 1 statis css file, and that is being served to your browser.

Comment: What if the problem is still there?

Comment: make sure to reload server for assets to recompile

Answer (score 0):

Have you include that `products.css.scss` in the `application.css` manifest file that you are referencing in the layout?

With the asset pipeline enabled, you must include the manifest in the layout and reference all the stylesheets from the manifest.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tania, thanks for your answer:

but the following lines (in application.html.erb) :

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    
    <body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'> #which translates to products

are these not supposed to make the scope-level stylesheet (products controller level) to be picked up and loaded? is application.css not for application-wide styles?

Sorry if I'm wrong. That's because I am new to rails and am trying to figure things out. Please enlighten and correct me.

Comment: Well, I am not a Rails expert, but I think that you are wrong. Rails will not include automatically any file, no matter if there is a css file with the same name that the controller. For Rails >= 3.1 using the asset pipeline, you include the application.css (also known as manifest) in the layout.It is in this file where you indicate which files you want to include. The directive `*= require_tree .` is the one that includes all the css files contained in the app/assets/stylesheets directory but it doesnt depend on the body class name. If you have read anywhere sth different, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Running the assets precompile command will compile as the user above mentioned... however, that might not be what you want to do unless you want to have to run that everytime you make a change and then add all of this to your SCM repo and then possibly have issues in production.

The real solution to this exact example is that the  doesn't have the "products" class in it, so the products.css.scss isn't picked up.  See this post which helped me understand this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080134

Answer (score 0):

place the `depot.css` from `/public/stylesheets/` to `app/assets/stylesheets/`

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/StylesheetTagHelpers/stylesheet_link_tag) you can set the tag to include all stylesheets in the stylesheets directory with stylesheet_link_tag :all  There are also options for caching, recursion, and concatenation.

If you don't want to include everything but just the application.css and your controller's css you could do this:

= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', params[:controller].classify.downcase.pluralize